# Test Match and Order between two vectors in R

Tags: r, match

I would like to test the match and order between two vectors. I'm aware of the match function; are there overlays to assess the order simultaneously? For example:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- c("b", "a", "c")   
x %in% y
```

There are perfect matches, but the ordering is not correct. Thoughts on how to identify that? Thanks.

Comment: try `all.equal(x,y)` to see if ordering is the same, and `all.equal(sort(x),sort(y))` to see if same content but different order

Comment: One simple measure of order would be `mean(x==y)` - a third of your example are in the same place.  If you want to measure order in some other way (number of pairwise swaps that would transform one into the other, cycles, ...), then we'll need to know what orders you'd consider similar.

Comment: How about just `x[x == y]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test_match_order <- function(x,y) {

if (all(x==y)) print('Perfect match in same order')

if (!all(x==y) && all(sort(x)==sort(y))) print('Perfect match in wrong order')

if (!all(x==y) && !all(sort(x)==sort(y))) print('No match')
}

test_match_order(x,y)

[1] "Perfect match in wrong order"
```

And here is another version based on my original comment above with an improvement from @alexis_laz below that makes the function more robust:

```
test_match_order2 <- function(x,y) {

if (isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))) print('Perfect match in same order')

if (!isTRUE(all.equal(x,y)) && isTRUE(all.equal(sort(x),sort(y)))) print('Perfect match in wrong order')

if (!isTRUE(all.equal(x,y)) && !isTRUE(all.equal(sort(x),sort(y)))) print('No match')
}
```

Comment: Using `==` looks a bit vulnerable; e.g. `xx = c(1-0.9, 0.2); yy = c(0.2, 0.1); xx; yy; test_match_order(xx, yy)`

Comment: @alexis_laz good point. does OP have a scenario like this in which redeclaring type would be more robust?

Comment: OP seems to be satisfied :). Your `all.equal` approach in your comment (wrapped inside a `isTRUE(.)`) seems to have less surprises, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I liked `all.equal` better but didn't know how to ensure output as boolean and avoid the descriptors of variation that it produces when `FALSE`. Thanks for `isTRUE()` -- that's new to me.  Cool :)