# R - compare diviance in order of sequence of vectors to a vector

Tags: r, vector, comparison, sequence

Given a vector:

```
x = c(1,0,1,0)
```

can be arranged in the following manner:

```
> m 
row1:    1    1    0    0
row2:    1    0    1    0 # <- identical
row3:    0    1    1    0
row4:    1    0    0    1
row5:    0    1    0    1
row6:    0    0    1    1
```

I would like to calculate how many diviations, or changes are required to each vector in each row one would have to perform to end up with the original vector `x`

```
result <- function(m,x)
> result                               
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4    changes_from_x
    1    1    0    0                     1
    1    0    1    0                     0
    0    1    1    0                     1
    1    0    0    1                     1
    0    1    0    1                     2
    0    0    1    1                     1
```

this is different from just comparing if the vector is the same [Compare two vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581737/compare-two-vector-in-r)
[Check whether two vectors contain the same (unordered) elements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912800/check-whether-two-vectors-contain-the-same-unordered-elements-in-r)
or to simply state that it's the wrong order or not [Test Match and Order between two vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392963/test-match-and-order-between-two-vectors-in-r) as the method would compare how many diviations has occured between each vector in the matrix and the original vector.

Comment: Does this work for you `colSums(t(result) != x) %/% 2` ?

Comment: yes - can you put it as an answer?